# How to perform triple tap on element in appium 1.6

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am trying to achieve a triple tap action on an element(IOS) less than 2 seconds using appium 1.6, tried below code but it is throwing an error.

```
new IOSTouchAction(driver).Tap(ele).Tap(ele).Tap(ele).perform();
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
  new IOSTouchAction(driver).tap(element).perform();
}
```

But no use.

- Appium: 1.6.3
- JavaClient: 5.0.0-BETA5/4.1.2

Please let me know if anyone has achieved this using above specs, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not with your code but with apple's Instruments.

It's a known issue that Instruments is forcing a 1 second delay between each action. to solve this try and configure "Instruments without delay". it worked for me!

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/iwd_xcode7.md

After configuring this, i believe that your "for" loop will work as expected

Comment: Thanks for this, let me try this :)

Comment: Raghu, did you see any improvements in speed? if overall speed is still the same, maybe the configuration did not work. are you using ios 9 emulator or ios 10?

Comment: David, I didn't see any improvements in terms of speed. BTW, I am using physical device (iPhone 6; iOS 9.3.5) and  xCode 8.2 & Appium 1.6.3)